# Prove that $A_n$ is simple for all $n \geq 5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a hard time understanding this part of the proof:

Suppose $n \geq 5$ and $N \unlhd A_n$ is non-trivial and contains a 3-cycle $(a,b,c)$. Let $(a',b',c')$ be any 3-cycle in $A_n$. Let $\pi\in S_n$ be such that $a^{\pi}=a'$, $b^{\pi}=b'$, $c^{\pi}=c'$. Then $\pi\in A_n$. Indeed, if $\pi$ is odd, then since $n \geq 5$, we may replace $\pi$ by $\pi(d,e)$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are distinct. We conclude that $(a',b',c') = (a,b,c)^{\pi} \in N^{\pi} = N$. So that $N=A_n$ which is a contradiction.

I don't understand why "if $\pi$ is odd, then since $n \geq 5$, we may replace $\pi$ by $\pi(d,e)$", Also I don't understand why $(a',b',c') = (a,b,c)^{\pi}$, because it seems to be the case that $(a,b,c)^{\pi}=(a,b,c)(...a,a'...b,b'...c,c')(d,e)=(...a,b'...c,a'...b,c'...)(d,e)$.

Comment: This was definitely asked and answered here before. Do some searching, please.

Comment: But none of them used this version of proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(a\,b\,c)^\pi=\pi^{-1}\circ (a\,b\,c)\circ \pi$.
So for example if $\pi(a')=a$ and $\pi(b')=b$, then $(a\,b\,c)^\pi(a')=\pi^{-1}((a\,b\,c)(\pi(a')))=\pi^{-1}((a\,b\,c)(a))=\pi^{-1}(b)=b'$ as desired.

The formulation of the proof seems odd, however. Instead of "Then $\pi \in A_n$", we can at most say "Then we may assume wlog that $\pi\in A_n$" (becasue if it is not, we can replace it with a different permutation that is)

Comment: but why is $\pi(a')=a$?  and why is $((abc)(a))=(b)$? The assumption was that $a^{\pi}=a'$.